# Want to migrate content and page from Tridion to IBM WCM

Tags: 2011, core-service, content-manager, componentpresentation, c#

Want to migrate content and Pages from the Tridion to the WCM.

Here need is the content and page source from the CMS.

Want to read the Source and store it on the local machine

How to proceed with it if they need the content and page source from tridion.

one should read the component source and store it or just by reading the individual page source it covers all the CPs PT is this sufficient.

Please provide your inputs

The WCM team will do the mapping they have another system for that so please tell me how to read the content and page source from the tridion end

Comment: By 'source' do you mean Tridion Component/Page XML or rendered source?

Comment: Now i had clear idea need the individual Component XML from the tridion without passing hardcoded tcm id of the component. I think if we get the XML will also get the meatadata, images, links used in that component. How to read the component xml

Answer (score 4):

You could also create a Tridion Custom Deployer and then 'publish' the content from Tridion into IBM WCM.  The advantage of this approach is that you can use the Tridion Deployer Java APIs and also your favorite Java IDE and ceremony.  The format of the data will be what the Tridion template produces.  So, for example, if your Tridion template produced XML (as the default DD4T templates do) then the Page in the Tridion Publish Package (sent to the Deployer) would be the XML format you defined (or the DD4T format, for example).

One example of a Custom Deployer that writes content to Amazon S3 and also MongoDB is here: https://github.com/aeyckerman/tridion-camel-extension

Note:  This is a complex idea and also piece of code that would need some serious time to examine how it works and learn how to install and use a Custom Deployer.

Another advantage to this approach is that anyone can "publish" the items to the IBM WCM.    You don't need to run the 'export script' from a developer.  You could also move items over piece by piece, or section by section.  Using the Java tooling also might be an advantage.

The disadvantages are that it is a complex thing to build, and it takes a while to get it set up and grep the idea.  You also need to define the output format (XML, for example) of the content being published.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague to me, but that might also be your English. There are basically two ways you can get content out of SDL Tridion, you either use the Core Service API (as Raj suggests), or you can use Content Porter and export the data you want (Content Porter will export it in a zip file, and in there you will find all the XML data from the items you exported).

Since SDL Tridion uses a structure of Pages and Components, you will need to restructure the data you get into what your target CMS will need yourself. That doesn't change from either of the options.

There is maybe a third option I could mention, and that is to scrape the content from the website which was published by SDL Tridion. Again this is all depending on what your target CMS requires as input for this migration, and depending on what migration tools you are using.

But that brings me to my last remark, it is a migration, and I know that developers tend to think "Automate" when they hear migration. I have written a blog post about migrations and my personal experiences once, and I came to the conclusion that you are most of the time better off hiring so called cheap labor and do the migration manually. That giives better results in the end, since you don't have to deal with possible faults in your exported data and can apply simple human logic (hey this link doesn't work anymore, let me try and find a replacement or remove it).

You can find my blog post here http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-to-say-goodbye-to-your-migration-tool

Comment: +1 for manual migration and humans working full-time on editing, massaging, and validating imported content.  Often times it is cheaper and higher quality to manually migrate sites with sane amounts of content.

Answer (score 1):

**Content**

First you need to understand your target CMS

- How it structure the content
- Any service/API available on target cms for ingestion
- You can write custom utility to migrate content after above steps.

**From Tridion:**

You can always use Core-Service to get your content & metadata and convert to the format required by your Custom utility which in-turns insert the content in Target CMs or Direct API.

**Templates:**

If you are using Dreamweaver template than, i don't think much scope of migration of design
templates.
but if DD4t there is some scope of re-utilizing the existing designs.

Comment: The WCM team expecting just the content and page source from tridion, mapping will be managed by their end, so please give me idea how to read the content and page source from tridion

Comment: I have given generic solution, i am not aware about your target CMS, how it works, also i see some gap in your expectations. if you want need just content not metadata, you can use Webdav to extract component xmls. Pages in Tridion are set of components & templates you might have to give that mapping.

Comment: i forgot to mention there are metadata, images, keywords categories etc. my question is that if we read the page source that is sufficient right because page source consists of the CPs, PT and Page metadata. Before its going to the target CMS they have framewok which will do the mapping, just need the content, metadata, categories,binary links and page source from the tridion CMS.